# Trying to change a jquery element from display: hidden to display: block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to using Jquery. Currently, the errorSummaryDiv element is not displaying. I am trying to write the code to change the element from display: none to display: block or just get rid of the display:none attribute altogether. For some reason I can't get my css to change from hidden to block with the below code. What am I doing incorrectly? I know the if statement is evaluating to true, because 'hi' is being logged in the console. Do you have to do something special that I am missing? Thank you in advance.

HTML:

```
<div class = "errorSummaryDiv">
    <h3>You have the following errors: </h3>
    <ul id="errors"></ul>
</div>
```

Jquery/Js:

```
if($('#errors').children().length === 0) {
        console.log('hi');
        $('div.errorSummaryDiv').css('display', 'block');

    }
```

css:

```
.errorSummaryDiv {
    display: none;
    width: 55%;
    background-color: #FFF69E;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #555;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

div {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `hide` / `show` method of jquery like:

```
$('.errorSummaryDiv').hide();  // To hide

$('.errorSummaryDiv').show();  // To show
```

**Explanation:** `hide()` will put `display:none` css on the element on which it is called and vice versa

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z9nafywy/)

**Note:** Don't forget to include jquery library in your code

Comment: Hey. Thanks for answering so quickly. I tried the .show(); function, but it's not doing anything either. Is there anything else that could be the issue? It still says display: hidden when I inspect the div in the elements tab. Is it possible its not finding the element based on the class?

Comment: I feel really dumb... I got it to work. I just wasn't calling the function. I commented out my document.ready function that calls the function that changes the css. I'm not sure why the console was outputting 'hi' though, but its working now. Thank you though!

Comment: That's great !!

Answer (score 0):

`$('div.errorSummaryDiv').show()`
should remove display:none